# MomentJs and dayjs both have wrong date for timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, dayjs

I'm running this code at 9:21am in London UK on Wednesday 10 August.

```
  console.log(moment.tz(date, "America/New_York").startOf("day"), "start!")
  console.log(moment.tz(date, timezone).startOf("day"), "timezone current!")
```

(also ran with dayjs replacing moment, results the same)

the first log returned: `Tue Aug 02 2022 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) {}`

the second returned: `Wed Aug 03 2022 01:00:00 GMT+0100`

The second is correct (mostly), I'd expect `00:00:00`but at least the date is right

The time currently in NY is 04:21 so why does it think the current startOf('day') date is yesterday when clearly it's still today?

Comment: What's the value of the date and timezone variables?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis having just run it date gives me back a moment object with the value: `Wed Aug 10 2022 09:33:03 GMT+0100`

Comment: here is a sandbox demonstrating the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/moment-timezone-test-forked-8ioms1

Comment: I'm passing in 5th August and it renders 4th?

Comment: Hi @RedBaron, I'm not sure to understand what you are expected, but in your sandbox you create a moment instance with the value `Wed Aug 05 2022` without time specified so it'll be 00:00 by default. My browser is in GMT+0200 so the default moment format should return `2022-08-05T00:00:00+02:00`, if I write this : `moment(date).tz("America/Denver").format()` it will display `2022-08-04T16:00:00-06:00`. That's sounds correct.

Comment: @JoffreyK after much being stupid on my part I realised that too ha. is it possible to send a date (say 5th) without a time? I just want my code to use the current date (in that timezone) with 00:00:00 as the time?

Comment: Oh I see your point, but is it relevant to handle timezone if you manually set hours / minutes to 00:00 ? I mean, timezones are just a display problem but the timestamp stay unchanged. If you want to change the timezone of your date object while keeping the same displayed informations (`2022-08-05T00:00:00` in your example), it means that you are no longer on the same timestamp... Anyway time zones are just hell, so good luck :).